# ¿Cuándo es necesario/posible no usar los artículos?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, artículos

Por ejemplo: *¿Dónde puedo cambiar dólares?*

Por qué no se escribe: ¿Dónde puedo cambiar *los* dólares?

Comment: Sí puedes escribir la segunda opción, pero con eso te refieres **específicamente** a ciertos dólares.